# Show a file using an overloaded function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How can I print a file of a structure using an overloaded function?

I have a overcharged function SHOW that prints a symbol and an array, but also need to print a file that is of a structure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void show(char c)
{
    cout << "\n Symbol: " << c << endl;
}

void show(int* m, int n)
{
    cout << "\n Array: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << m[i] << ((i == n-1) ? "" : ", ");
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int m[10] = {16,  78,  99,   6, -29,  19, -52,  65, -88,  51};
    show(m, 10);
    show('a');

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: _overcharged function_

Comment: You should provide a new overload `void show(FILE* my_file)`. What have you tried ?

Comment: @GeorgeAl and how it would be in the main function?

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file with std::ifstream (`#include <fstream>`) and stream it in console :

```
void show(std::string filepath)
{
    //file reader
    std::ifstream file(filepath);
    std::string strline;
    // while you're not at the end of the file, read the current line
    while(getline(file, strline)) 
        //display the line in console
        std::cout << strline<< std::endl;
}
```